# How to know that aggregated group has previous/next values?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.getCollection('posts').aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: { $gt: "some id" }, tag: 'some tag' } },
    { $limit: 5 },
    { $group: { _id: null, hasNextPage: {??}, hasPreviousPage: {??} } }
])
```

As a result `$match` and `$limit` stages would result in a subset of all the posts with a tag `some tag`. How can I know that there're posts before and after my subSet?

One of the possible ways, I guess, is to have expression (with `$let`) inside `hasPreviousPage` and `hasNextPage` that would search for one post with `_id` less than `"some id"` and greater than `$last: "$_id"`respectively. But I'm not sure how I can reference my group as a variable in `$let`. Also, maybe there're some other more effective ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    { $match: { tag: 'some tag' } },
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
    {
        $facet: {
            data: [
                { $match: { _id: { $gt: 'some id' } } },
                { $limit: 5 }
            ],
            hasPreviousPage: [
                { $match: { _id: { $lte: 'some id' } } },
                { $count: "totalPrev" }
            ],
            hasNextPage: [
                { $match: { _id: { $gt: 'some id' } } },
                { $skip: 5 },
                { $limit: 1 }, // just to check if there's any element
                { $count: "totalNext" }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: { path: "$hasPreviousPage", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
    },
    {
        $unwind: { path: "$hasNextPage", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            data: 1,
            hasPreviousPage: { $gt: [ "$hasPreviousPage.totalPrev", 0 ] },
            hasNextPage: { $gt: [ "$hasNextPage.totalNext", 0 ] }
        }
    }
])
```

To apply any paging you have to [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) your collection to get results in deterministic order. On a set that's sorted and filtered by `tag` you can run [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) which allows you to apply multiple subaggregations. Pipelines that are representing previous and nextPage can be ended with `$count`. Every subaggregation in `$facet` will return an array so we can run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get nested document instead of array for `hasPreviousPage` and `hasNextPage`. Option `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` is required here cause otherwise MongoDB will remove whole document from aggregation pipeline if there are no prev / next documents. In the last step we can just convert subaggregations to boolean values.